# Receiving notification of a chat response

Tags: support, chat, notifications

Is it possible to get some sort of a notification that a chat that I'm involved in has been replied to?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean be "a chat that I'm involved in", and what do you mean by "replying to a chat"?

Comment: I currently have a chat that came from an answer, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2706/discussion-between-david-lozzi-and-mike, I would like to know when this chat as activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person *replies* to you, either using the reply button on one of your messages, or by using a `@reply` with your name, then yes, you will get a notification (first in the live chat, and if you're not there or haven't seen it after ~15 minutes, also in your global inbox).

For the mere fact that someone is/was talking in a particular room, there is no notification.